# Multivariate Order Statistics (Binomial Distribution)

Tags: probability, statistics, binomial-distribution, covariance, order-statistics

If $X_i\sim B(1, p_i), i=1, ..., n,$ all independent. Let $Q=\min(X_1,\ldots, X_n)$ and $W = \max(X_1, \ldots, X_n).$ Find the correlation between $Q$ and $W.$

Computing correlation by the usual definition
$$ \frac{Cov(Q,W)}{\sqrt{\text{Var}(Q) \text{Var}(W)}}$$
is always a very long and tedious approach. Is there any shortcuts to doing this without using the definition?

For example if I consider a bivariate case where $q_i = 1-p_i.$ Then

$E(Q)=E(\min(X_1,X_2)) = p_1, \text{Var}(Q) = p_1 q_1$,

$E(W)=E(\max(X_1,X_2))= q_1, \text{Var}(W) = p_1 q_1,$ so that

$$ Cov(QW) = E(QW)-E(Q)E(W)= E(X_1)E(X_2) - E(Q) E(W) = p_1q_1- p_1q_1 (p_1q_1) = p_1q_1- (p_1q_1)^2 $$
and

$$\sqrt{Var(Q) Var(W)} = \sqrt{(p_1q_1) (p_2q_2)} = p_1q_1.$$

If the results of this bivariate case is correct, how do I extend it in the mulvariate case with regard to my posted question for all $i= 1, \ldots, n?$ It seems to be $Cov(QW) = p_1q_1 - (p_1q_1)^n$ and $\sqrt{Var(QW)} = p_1q_1$ but I'm not sure of that.

Answer (score 1):

You do need to compute $\operatorname{Cov}(Q,W)$ and $\operatorname{Var}(Q)$ and $\operatorname{Var}(W)$. You can get everything from the joint distribution of $(Q,W)$, which is not difficult to obtain (see below). Once you have the joint distribution for $(Q,W)$, you can deduce the marginal distributions for $Q$ and $W$.

What is the joint distribution for $(Q,W)$? Notice that there are only three possible values for the pair $(Q,W)$: $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$, and $(1,1)$. The first case occurs when every $X_i$ equals zero; the third case occurs when every $X_i$ equals one. Your job is to compute the probabilities of these first and third cases; the middle case follows by subtraction.

Comment: Is this how you mean? \begin{align*}
P(X=0) = &
 (1-p_1)^{n} \ldots (1-p_n)^{n}\\
P(X=1) = &
 np_1(1-p_1)^{n} \ldots np_n(1-p_n)^{n}\\
\end{align*}
Using
$P(X=0) +P(X=1) + P(X=1,0) = 1,$ then
$$P(X=1,0) =  1-
np_1(1-p_1)^{n} \ldots np_n(1-p_n)^{n} -  (1-p_1)^{n} \ldots (1-p_n)^{n}$$

Comment: The event $\{(Q,W)=(0,0)\}$ is the same as the event $\{Q=0, W=0\}$. Explain why this is the same as the event $\{X_1=0, X_2=0, \ldots, X_n=0\}$, then use independence to compute the probability of this event. Note that $X_i$ has binomial$(1,p_i)$ distribution so $P(X_i=1) = p_i$ and $P(X_i=0)=q_i$.